# Drag and drop to remove an item from ListFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have the code for a fragment of the as follows that works very well:

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;

    private boolean mSubtitleVisible;

    private static final String SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE = "subtitle";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list,container,false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        if (null != savedInstanceState) {mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);}

        updateUI();

        return  view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE, mSubtitleVisible);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);

        MenuItem subtitleItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle);
        if (mSubtitleVisible) {subtitleItem.setTitle(R.string.hide_subtitle);}
        else {subtitleItem.setTitle(R.string.show_subtitle);}

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menu_item_new_crime:
            {
                Crime crime = new Crime();
                CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
                Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), crime.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle:
            {
                mSubtitleVisible = !mSubtitleVisible;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                updateSubtitle();
                return true;
            }
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void updateSubtitle()
    {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        int crimeCount = crimeLab.getCrimes().size();
        String subtitle = getString(R.string.subtitle_format,crimeCount);

        if (!mSubtitleVisible) {subtitle = null;}

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
    }
    private void updateUI()
    {
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes =crimeLab.getCrimes();

        if (null == mAdapter)
        {
            mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
            mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        else {mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();} 
        updateSubtitle();
    }
    private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        //public TextView mTitleTextView;
        private TextView mTitleTextView;
        private TextView mDateTextView;
        private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

        private Crime mCrime;

        public CrimeHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            //mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView;
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_title_text_view);
            mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_date_text_view);
            mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_solved_check_box);
        }

        public void bindCrime(Crime crime)
        {
            mCrime = crime;
            mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
            mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
            mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder>
    {
        private List<Crime> mCrimes;
        public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes){mCrimes = crimes;}
        @Override
        public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime/*android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1*/,parent,false);
            return new CrimeHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position) //finalmente a esta de aquí
        {
            Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
            /*holder.mTitleTextView.setText(crime.getTitle());*/
            holder.bindCrime(crime);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return mCrimes.size();
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to implement the examples of Drag and Swipe with `RecyclerView`, like [this](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) medium article:

But I only get errors.

What do I need to implement `onSwiped` and where?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you implement ItemTouchHelper? read the tutorial carefully.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering.

In my first I am beginner in Android.

My code is extension to fragment:

public class ListaFragmentoProducto extends Fragment  {

In the meantime the example extends to ItemTouchHelper.Callback:

public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

How can I join or use both extensions?

Thanks

Comment: I think I already made it. There is a bug out there, but I think it's the least.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lFCgjiNhOE&feature=youtu.be&a